# Appropriateness of [teaching] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag was recently [created](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/44948/revisions).  There are now three questions carrying the tag.

Its intended purpose is described in its tag wiki:

> Much like the [beginner] tag, this tag should call out that extra care
>   should be taken reviewing the code. Your code review might impact how
>   students learn about programming.

Should it stay or should it go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with 200's answer.

All reviews should be implicitly 'teaching': teaching the OP.

In contexts where 'teaching' might be useful (e.g. "we can't use exceptions here because we haven't covered those in class yet"), that fact can be a comment (the mere presence of the 'teaching' tag doesn't convey such sufficient/accurate/useful information).

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44505/34757) is an example of a teaching question without the teaching tag. The several sentences to that effect in the OP were necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not convinced that the tag should stay, because:

1. [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) is a meta-tag, describing the status of the question being asked, rather than the content.  On Stack Overflow, they have been [deprecating meta-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag).  I realize that we still have meta-tags like [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) and [homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), and I'm not currently pushing to eliminate them from Code Review, but I'm reluctant to introduce another.
2. Does that imply that we're normally a careless bunch?
3. Code Review, like anything on the Internet, relies on the collective wisdom of the crowd.  We all give dubious advice from time to time.  Some reviewers are more skilled than others.  Admonitions to be extra careful are unlikely to raise the quality of any answer.  However, reviewers correct each other, and good advice generally emerges from the variety of opinions.  That's how the process normally works; why should it be any different for [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) questions?

For those reasons, I propose removing the [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag from all three questions.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked the teaching flag, it's a shame it's gone.

1. I am aware that it's a meta flag, I think a number of them are useful. This one could be too.
2. [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) answers should prefer low tech solutions ( [It does not matter how beautiful functional code is, yet.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63981/finding-the-largest-averaged-array?noredirect=1#comment117005_63989) )
3. [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) commenting will be different, you might actually have valid 'obvious' comments

   ```
   //add 1 to x with an addition assignment.
   x += 1;
   ```
4. Terribly personal, but this kind of questions interest me in any programming language. They are geared towards students, I might actually learn something new on CR. I for one <del>welcome our new teaching overlords</del>, would track [teaching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) questions.