# Am I violating the [beginner] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I consider myself a beginner, therefore I usually end up using the [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag.

For these questions, am I violating the [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag?

1. [Reverse Polish notation based compiler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67480/reverse-polish-notation-compiler)
2. [Code Generator Generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/code-generator-generator)

Also keep in mind that I consider myself a beginner when it comes to C++ and Perl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting the tag excerpt:

> Add this tag to your question to indicate that you are new to the
>   language of your code.

So I'd say: **No**, you are not violating the tag ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The best one to decide if you are a beginner or not is yourself.

If you feel like a beginner in the language, go ahead and use the beginner tag.

It is hard to define a specific point where you cross the line from being a beginner to not being a beginner anymore, you will have to set that line yourself.